# Jquery dynamically wrap bootstrap columns in rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some code formatted as following:

```
<div id="section">
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

There can be any number (even or odd) of columns in this section.

What I want is for it to be re-formatted like this:

```
<div id="section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt to do so:

```
for (var x = 0; x < $('#section').children().length; x+=2) {
    var firstSection = $('#section').children().eq(x);
    if ($('#section').children().length >= x + 1) {
        var secondSection = $('#section').children().eq(x + 1);
        var finalSection = '<div class="row">' + firstSection.parent().html() + secondSection.parent().html() + '</div>';
        secondSection.remove();
    }
    else {
        var finalSection = '<div class="row">' + firstSection.html() + '</div>';
    }

    firstSection.remove();
    $('#section').append(finalSection);
}
```

If anyone wants some extra fun, you could try allowing this to handle variable column widths as well! (Although I don't need that for my project).

Comment: Is it max 2 per `row`, what is the rational for determining that.

Comment: If it exceeds 2 per row then the column will overflow onto a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hers is an example that loops through the columns, similar to what you are attempting now.

It uses `find()`, `append()` and `clone()` to accomplish this task.  As an added feature I wrapped it into a function that accepts the **row size** as an argument.

```js
//breaks up the section into rows of size 'rowSize', 2 by default.
function breakitup(rowSize = 2) {
  var $section = $("#section"); //get the section
  var $row = $("<div class='row'>"); //make a template for a row
  var cols = $section.find("div"); //get the columns
  var working; //tmp variable for the current row
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    if (i % rowSize == 0) working = $row.clone(); //clone the template when appropriate
    $(working).append(cols[i]); //add the column to the row
    if ($(working).children().length == rowSize) 
      $section.append(working); //add the row to the section as appropriate
  }
  $section.append(working); //add the last row
}
//call our fancy function
breakitup();
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
  <div class="col-xs-6">test</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">test7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.wrapall()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/), [.add()](https://api.jquery.com/add/) and [:even](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector:

```js
$('#section > div:even').each(function(idx, ele) {
    $(ele).add($(this).next()).wrapAll($('<div/>', {class: 'row'}));
});


console.log($('#section').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section">
    <div class="col-xs-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">7</div>
</div>
```